Run multiple vector samples at once
I am trying to create a command that runs multiple random vector samples simultaneously and give me all the selected variables at once.
I can get what I want by having code like:
sample(vector1, 1); sample(vector2, 1)...
But when I try to link the sequence to a command prompt it keeps giving me the same variable from only the first sampler over and over. I would greatly appreciate suggestions on how to fix this
